# Disabling a Windows domain user account on a single device?

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to create a PowerShell script to disable a user's account on a device that may not be connected to the domain controller and may have cached credentials.

For a local user I would just use `Disable-LocalAccount` but unfortunately that doesn't work for domain users. I've also tried using ADSI objects and `net user [USERNAME] /active:no` with no luck.

Comment: Might be helpful... https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Windows/en-US/110df5a0-bf87-4511-bd8c-d523258dca12/how-to-set-deny-logon-localy-in-ps-script?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: Would completely [disabling cached logins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/user-profiles-and-logon/cached-domain-logon-information) on the machine be an option? You could disable cached logins then just have the machine reboot. User won't be able to login until they connect back to the domain.